# Spoiler request: what happens at the end of the Wheel of Time series?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

When I was much younger, I started reading Robert Jordan's wheel of time series. I very much enjoyed the early books, but I gave up at a certain point because the books where getting longer while the story progressed at a slower rate, and there were an awful lot of books.

Now that the series is finished I'm somewhat curious to know what happened in the end, but I'm definitely not going to go back and read them all now. So this is basically a request for a massive spoiler: please tell how the story is resolved. Does the protagonist eventually manage to kill all 13(?) of the Forsaken? (He was picking them off at a rate of approximately one per book when I stopped reading.) Does he defeat the Evil One, and if so how? What happens after that?

I recall that every book began with a section in italics explaining that time in this world is cyclic. (Or at least that was how I took it; perhaps it wasn't meant to be literal.) Does this ever become directly relevant to the story? There were some hints that the past was more technically advanced than the present, which I took to be because it is also the future. I always hoped that there would be events at the end of the story that have some causal influence on events at the beginning. Does this actually happen?

I've looked online for this information, but couldn't find it in a digestable form. There are some spoiler reviews of the last book, but they assume you've read the series, rather than explaining its plot. Wikipedia of course has a thorough point-by-point plot synopsis of each book, but it's far too long and detailed to get an idea of overall thrust of the story.

Similarly, I'm not looking for chapter-by-chapter summaries. That's far more detail than I want. I'd just like to know what happens at the end, that's all.

For example, if I were asking about the Lord of the Rings a perfectly good answer would be

> Frodo eventually makes it to Mount Doom but can't bring himself to destroy the ring. However, Gollum has followed him and attempts to grab it off him, but accidentally slips and falls into one of the cracks of doom. Thus the ring is destroyed and Middle Earth is saved. Also, along the way Gandalf gets killed by a creature called a Balrog and comes back as Gandalf the White instead of Gandalf the Grey. After the ring is destroyed, many of the main characters leave Middle Earth and sail for somewhere called the Undying Land.

Comment: I hope this kind of "spoiler request" question is acceptable here. I did search the meta site but didn't come up with anything - apologies if I missed it.

Comment: Well, it's an involved story.  It's a bit like asking "what happens in Martian Chronicles?"  You can say "well, they move to Mars," but that really bastardizes the story unless you explain it further - which takes a while.  In essence, you're just asking someone to take a lot of time summarizing the story for you instead of going and taking the time to read one of the many summaries already out there.

Comment: This is a bit too vague. "I want a summary that assumes that I know a bit about the world but not too much, and doesn't go into too much detail, but doesn't assume I've read the books recently" is extremely vague - the right answer for *you* is impossible to get right without a lot of back and forth with you to elaborate on some aspects but downplay othesrs, and the Stack Exchange format isn't built for that. And frankly, that's asking a lot out of people.

Comment: What you can do is go to the [WoT Encyclopedia](http://encyclopaedia-wot.org/) and read the chapter-by-chapter summaries. An hour or so and you have the whole plot.

Comment: http://www.thonky.com/wot/all-summaries.php

Comment: Rand eventually removes the taint from Saidin, unites the world against the Dark One, then seals the remaining Forsaken and the Dark One back into a new prison. There ya go.

Comment: Very late comment I know, but @Omegacron you forgot - and dies, but doesn't die.

Answer (score 5):

A good summary that matches your requirements would be hard to give, since they include "easily digestable" but also "don't assume I've read previous books" but also answer questions that *do* assume knowledge of the series, like "Has Rand killed off all of the Forsaken". It's just too specific for anyone to give an answer that fits.

What I can recommend is to read summaries of the books to get up to speed:

1. Wikipedia has [book-by-book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wheel_of_Time#Books_in_the_series) plot summaries that are pretty high level, usually 5-6 bullet point paragraphs.
2. The [Encyclopedia WoT](http://encyclopaedia-wot.org/) has detailed chapter-by-chapter summaries, including cross-references and salient details introduced in the chapter.
3. [The Wheel of Time True Online Source](http://www.thonky.com/wot/) has much thinner chapter-by-chapter summaries, usually one or two paragraphs.

These should help you fill up the gaps.